# Using FullCalendar with Backbone and Require

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, fullcalendar, require

I am trying to use FullCalender.js with backbone and requirejs.  The trouble is I don't seem to be able to get it declared in a requirejs set up.

So far I have added it to the View define statement, but that doesn't work.  I just get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'fullCalendar'
```

This it the view:

```
define([
 'jqueryui',
 'underscore',
 'backbone',
 'utils',
 'fullcalendar',

 'Collection/EventCollection',
 'model/EventModel'

], function ($, _, Backbone, Utils, fullCalendar, EventCollection, EventModel){

var EventView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#singlecolumn",
    initialize: function(models){
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.eventCollection = models.model;
        this.eventCollection.bind('reset', this.addAll);
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log("Rendering Calendar...");
        this.el.fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',
                ignoreTimezone: false
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: true
        });
    },

    addAll: function(){
        console.log("Rendering Calendar...");
        this.el.fullCalendar('addEventSource', this.eventCollection.toJSON());
    }

});

return EventView;
});
```

Anyone done this already?

Comment: Have u tried to change this.el to this.$el ?

Comment: Of course...now I feel like a fool for posting such a stupid question!  ;-)  Thanks for your help.